# gevent monkey_path thread id

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, gevent, monkeypatching

```
from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()

import threading
import time


def printer():
    current_thread = threading.current_thread()
    print(current_thread.ident)
    # time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_thread = threading.current_thread()
    print(current_thread.ident)
    threading.Thread(target=printer).start()
    threading.Thread(target=printer).start()
    threading.Thread(target=printer).start()
```

and the result is :

```
140482707396456
140482679461960
140482679461960
140482679461960
```

This is expected since gevent monkey patch will transform threading into coroutine which all have the same thread id. However, after uncomment 'time.sleelp', the thread ids all change:

```
from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()

import threading
import time


def printer():
    current_thread = threading.current_thread()
    print(current_thread.ident)
    time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_thread = threading.current_thread()
    print(current_thread.ident)
    threading.Thread(target=printer).start()
    threading.Thread(target=printer).start()
    threading.Thread(target=printer).start()


140504830732136
140504802797640
140504802797896
140504802798152
```

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: I also face the same problem. Have you found the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

`monkey.patch_all()` patches `time` so that `time.sleep` becomes `gevent.sleep`, which does a cooperative yield to other greenlets. With `monkey.patch_all()`, the print statement should also do a cooperative yield. Therefore there's no guarantee that the 3 thread id's should be the same, but in your case they were without the `time.sleep` call.

You can add a print statement to see when the function exits, which should be helpful for seeing when the greenlets start & exit.

```py
def printer():
    current_thread = threading.current_thread()
    print(current_thread.ident)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print('%i is exiting'%current_thread.ident)
```